# dynamically add facebook profile pic view in table row android

Tags: android, facebook, android-tablelayout

I have a small question. In my table row I want to add a FacebookProfilePictureView and this causes some errors for me apart from adding a simple ImageView. I am attaching a picture that shows the output that I receive.

[image]

The white box to the right of the serial number is where profilepicview is set, all the time. Also, in xml I have set the size to 50,50 (width, height) but in java it gets messy. My codes are below.

XML code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_below_linear_layout_three_team_spuck"
    android:id="@+id/the_maintable_team_spuck"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/the_maintable_row_team_spuck">

        <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
            android:id="@+id/profile_pic_view_team_spuck"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Java code:

```
the_normal_image_view = new ImageView(view.getContext());  // this is the normal image view, no issues when adding this in table
profilePictureView = new ProfilePictureView(view.getContext()); // this is the profile pic view


the_maintable_row_team_spuck.removeAllViews();
the_maintable_row_team_spuck.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams
        ( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

the_maintable_row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);


/*the_smallperson_team_spuck.setImageResource(R.drawable.the_smallperson);
the_smallperson_team_spuck.setPadding(7, 7, 15, 0);*/


profilePictureView.setPadding(7, 7, 15, 0);

//the_maintable_row.addView(the_normal_image_view);  // adding normal image view into row
the_maintable_row.addView(profilePictureView);            // adding fb profile pic view in to row

the_maintable.addView(the_maintable_row_team_spuck, new TableRow.LayoutParams
        (TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load user Profile Image to ImageView Then you should try this

**Step 1** ImageView

```
 <ImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

**Step 2** put this line on oncreate method to load image when open screen

```
new DownloadImage(imgUserProfile).execute(userProfileUrl);
```

**Step 3** MainActivity.java

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
ImageView imgUserProfile;
imgUserProfile = (ImageView).findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

**Step 4** method for AcyncTask Mehod Name: DownloadImage()

```
 public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (CircleImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i have the ID's for the friends, then?

Comment: but where you use friend's Id ?
I think you want to only show profile photo rite ?

Comment: tell me what you want to load in ImageView ?